# Choosing the right hreflang tags

Tags: php, session, hreflang

For a customer I need to auto-detect the language based on the browser language. The user should not be redirected to another URL.

So my solution was to store the language information in a session cookie.

For example:
*User visits "example.com". His language is German. So the content will be available in German without redirection.
Same with English, URL is always the same.*

But now I have a problem with using hreflang tags.

Which tags should I use to tell Google that SERPs in Austria/Germany/Switzerland have to be shown in German and anywhere else in English?

To switch a language I'm using a GET-Parameter, e.g. ?lang=de

I hope anybody can help me.

Edit:
Actually I have the following tags:

```
<link rel=alternate hreflang=x-default href="http://example.com/">
<link rel=alternate hreflang=de href="http://example.com/?lang=de">
<link rel=alternate hreflang=en href="http://example.com/?lang=en">`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use Hreflang tags if your pages in different languages have different URLs. If you use query string parameters then http://example.com/page?lang=de and http://example.com/page?lang=en are actually 2 separate URLs and 2 separate pages. So on each page you can use this markup:

```
<link rel=alternate hreflang=de href="http://example.com/page?lang=de">
<link rel=alternate hreflang=en href="http://example.com/page?lang=en">
```

Note that both tags should be on both pages.

Comment: Thank you. That's actually what I tried but the results for the main page will be displayed in English in Austria/Germany/Switzerland instead of German.

Comment: what's your website?